# Extract anchor tags from request URI

Tags: java, html, jsf

Is it possible to extract anchor tags form request URL in Java Server Faces?
I can extract the link and query parameters but I can't find a way to extract anchor tags, e.g. I have  a link `localhost:8181/application/config#USER_CONFIG`.
I have an interceptor that needs to do logic based on which anchor tag I provide (in this case `#USER_CONGIF`).

But I can't find a way to extract the anchor tag from the request URL.

Answer (score 0):

According to this

[How can i read html anchor in java servlet?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4276259/how-can-i-read-html-anchor-in-java-servlet)

anchors are note send from client to server and so you can not get them in a Servlet env (such as JSF).