# access # part of the URL via PHP

Tags: php

Say I have this url.

```
http://mydomain.local/category/12/garden#31/decking-treatment
```

Can the part after the # i.e `31/decking-treatment` be retrieved on serverside?

I checked in the `$_SERVER` and `$_REQUEST` superglobals but it is not there.

Thanks

Regards
Gabriel

Comment: what are you trying to do with the parts after the #?

Comment: use it to know what should be rendered. The hash is added via javascript after an ajax call.

Comment: So basically when you update the page with AJAX you are trying to reflect the update in the URI?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to obtain anchor part of URL after # in php](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1032242/how-to-obtain-anchor-part-of-url-after-in-php)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Can the part after the # i.e 31/decking-treatment be retrieved on serverside?

No. It is handled client side and never sent to the server. That is why using it for JS based history instead of `pushState` [is a bad idea](http://isolani.co.uk/blog/javascript/BreakingTheWebWithHashBangs).

Answer (score 1):

No, everything after the # is only ever used client side and will not hit the server. If you were to encode the # character before pushing it to the server then you might be able to do something but it would be a little long winded. What is it you are trying to acheive overall?

Comment: Basically I have an ajax based menu. User clicks on an item of the menu and a div gets refreshed. Onclick .. I added the hash part to the url. Reason being that if the user shares the link with someone. I want the other person to see the same information.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I sort it:

```
function reloadPage()
    {
        var hash = location.hash;
        if (hash){
            hash = hash.replace('#', '');
            location.href = hash;
        }
    }
```

reloadPage();

include this in your js file.